# Filter items based on another column value with result in one cell

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have table like this in excel:

```
   A  B  C
 -----------
1| a  t
2| b
3| c  t
4| d
5| e  t
6| f  t
```

and want select all values in column A where value in column B is 't'. There is no problem to select them with matrix formula like this:

```
=JEŻELI.BŁĄD(INDEKS(A1:A10;MIN.K(JEŻELI(B1:B10="t";WIERSZ(B1:B10);"");WIERSZ()));"")
```

but the problem is that I want send the result to one cell only (example result based on above table):

```
"a,c,e,f"
```

It is possible without writing a VBA code?

Comment: For future reference: please use English in your posts and not Polish. If you don't know a formula in English then simply go to the VBE and execute in the direct window: `? selection.formula` (while the cell is highlighted). In return, you will get the Excel formula translated into English.

Comment: Oops sorry I forgot about formula names in polish...

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365 Excel you can use TEXTJOIN as an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($B$1:$B$6 = "t",$A$1:$A$6,""))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when Exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

---

If you do not have Office 365 Excel or do not want to us an array formula then you will need a helper column.

In C1 put:

```
=IF(B1="t",A1&"," &C2,C2)
```

And copy down the length of the dataset.

Then in D1 put:

```
=LEFT(C1,LEN(C1)-1)
```

[image]